# Extension of the set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Given the set:

$$\{x | x \in \{a, b\}*~\text{AND}~|x| = 4~\text{AND}~\exists y \in \{a,b\}* : (x = aya)\}$$

Why does the answer look like this: $\{aaaa, aaba, abaa, abba\}$? What I don't understand is why $bbbb$ isn't part of the answer? Does $a$ means $x$ and $y$ means $b$? Could someone just translate the given set in plain English? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @BrianO, but what does `y` mean?

Comment: I moved my comment to an answer, so if it's still not clear, then ask again below the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the set $S$. It's defined by:
$$
x \in S \iff \lvert x\rvert = 4 \:\&\: \exists y \in \{a,b\}^*\, x = aya
$$
In plain English, a string over the alphabet $\{a,b\}$ is in $S$ if and only if

- its length is 4, and
- it begins and ends with $a$.

This leaves only the four possibilities $aa, ab, ba, bb$ for $y$, and any $x$ in $S$ will be $aya$ for one of those four possible $y$s.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! @BrianO. I'm confused about why there are only possibilities for y that are aa, ab, ba, bb when there is {a,b}*?

Comment: For $x$ in the set, $x$ has length 4 and begins and ends with $a$. So $x$ can be written $x = aya$ for some substring $y$ in the middle. So $y$ has to have length 2, and there are only 4 possibilities over the alphabet $\{a,b\}$. To really spell it out: $4 = |x| = |aya| = |a| + |y| + |a| = 1 + |y| + 1$.

Comment: That sounds like an "aha!" -- good :) You're welcome.